# Authentication in headers through credentials instead of cookie

Tags: php

I am accessing a url which needs authentication, so for authentication i am using cookie something like this

```
$out = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $host\r\nCookie: user=$cookie\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30) or htmlerror('Bandwidth limit exceeded, please try again later.');
fwrite($fp, $out);
```

so i wanted to know whether instead of cookie how can i use directly username and password in variable **$out**

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it didnt work, just using it with cookie

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick view on [HTTP GET REQUEST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html), you might try to insert something into the query part of the URI

> $out = 'GET /***?*username=$user&password=$encryptedPW** HTTP/1.1'
>
> $out .= '/n' . 'Host: $host'